# Neo4j session timeout

Tags: neo4j

Running something very simple from Rails:

```
w = Woka.first
Faraday::TimeoutError: too many connection resets (due to Net::ReadTimeout - Net::ReadTimeout) after 1 requests on 70293322572340, last used 60.011694 seconds ago
```

After that no other session can be established without restarting the server.

What server parameters should be changed here to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed again the file config/environemnts/development.rb

```
  config.neo4j.session_options = {
    basic_auth: { username: 'user', password: 'pass'},
    initialize: {
        request: {
            open_timeout: 2,   # opening a connection
            timeout: 1200      # waiting for response
        }
    }
  }
```

Problem solved.